# Can I change title and meta description with 301 redirect?

Tags: seo, 301-redirect

I would like to make 301 redirect from one page to another. Do I need to use the same titles and meta tags or I can change it to new one without losing the rank of the page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change the title and meta tags (which don't do anything for your rankings). All the 301 redirect does is tell users and search engines where the page has moved to. For SEO, this means all links pointing to the old URL will be associated with the new URL (minus a small dampening factor).